# undefined reference when compiling c++ project with g++

Tags: c++, windows, g++

I am trying to create a simple c++ application that utilizes the [libheif](https://github.com/strukturag/libheif) library.

My setup is Visual Studio Code and msys2, I followed the recommended setup guide for c++ and vscode

I have started by including the file `libheif` into one of the paths obtained using the command `cpp -v`,

I then tried to compile the basic example found on the libheif github page

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
extern "C" {
#include <libheif/heif.h>
}


int main() {
    const char *input_filename = "test.heic";
    heif_context* ctx = heif_context_alloc();
    heif_context_read_from_file(ctx, input_filename, nullptr);

    // get a handle to the primary image
    heif_image_handle* handle;
    heif_context_get_primary_image_handle(ctx, &handle);

    // decode the image and convert colorspace to RGB, saved as 24bit interleaved
    heif_image* img;
    heif_decode_image(handle, &img, heif_colorspace_RGB, heif_chroma_interleaved_RGB, nullptr);

    int stride;
    const uint8_t* data = heif_image_get_plane_readonly(img, heif_channel_interleaved, &stride);
}
```

I compile it and get the following errors

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g D:\Projects\ImageConverter\heic2jpg.cpp -o D:\Projects\ImageConverter\heic2jpg.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\wetha\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz86gv8.o:D:/Projects/ImageConverter/heic2jpg.cpp:10: undefined reference to `heif_context_alloc'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\wetha\AppData\Local\Temp\ccz86gv8.o: in function `main':
D:/Projects/ImageConverter/heic2jpg.cpp:11: undefined reference to `heif_context_read_from_file'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Projects/ImageConverter/heic2jpg.cpp:15: undefined reference to `heif_context_get_primary_image_handle'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Projects/ImageConverter/heic2jpg.cpp:19: undefined reference to `heif_decode_image'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Projects/ImageConverter/heic2jpg.cpp:22: undefined reference to `heif_image_get_plane_readonly'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**VCPKG**

g++

for g++ i ran the command
`g++ main.cpp -LD:/vcpkg -llibheif`

cmake

i installed cmake and created a CMakeLists.txt containing

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(test)

find_package(libheif)

add_executable(main heic2jpg.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE libheif::heif)
```

then ran the command

```
cmake .. "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake"
```

and got errors

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibheif
```

and got errors

```
 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libheif" with any
  of the following names:

    libheifConfig.cmake
    libheif-config.cmake
```

i have tried both of these with different varients of package names such has libheif_x86-windows.

Comment: You don't **link** with the `heif` library itself. Any decent tutorial, book or class should have information about how to link with libraries. And if the documentation for the `heif` library is good then it would contain a tutorial that tells you exactly what you need to build with it, including all the commands.

Comment: the github page under windows says the compilation method is ```vcpkg```, I installed ```vcpkg``` and then ran the command to install libheif, however the same error messages came up. does vcpkg sound like the definitive way to be installing this or is there something else i should be looking into

Comment: vcpkg will compile the library for you, but it doesn't automatically integrate the library with other projects unless you tell it to integrate with Visual Studio. For G++ like you're using you can use the the `-L` flag to tell it where to look for libraries to link against, and the `-l` flag to tell it which libraries to actually use. So use the flags `-L[path/to/install_dir]` and `-llibheif`

Comment: so i see the installed package in vcpkg, but i cannot get it to work by linking the build, basically neither g++ nor cmake can find the library file ... Ill add the extra details to the original post

Comment: use `-lheif`, not `-llibheif`

Comment: same error message ```cannot find -lheif``` what does the argument for -l actually refer to, is it looking for a folder name or a specific file

Comment: never ended up getting this to work with VSCode and the command line. But i did migrate everything over to Visual Studio Community and used the build in build tools and it worked flawlessly